# Changes made on php.ini have no effect on wordpress

Tags: php

[EDIT] Just managed to solve it. You just have to copy the php.ini **without the line tht adjusts the memory** into the wp-admin folder.

Recently, I tried to install a wordpress theme called Avada and ended up having trouble activating one of the plugins. I talked to the support, and they told me to fix avery issue shown on the system status window (see below for "1").

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHJKh.png

So I created a php.ini (see "2"), made the changes (I don't have a .htaccess file), saved it on my public_html, and checked again the system status window just to see it didn't work.

The thing is, publicphp() shows that it did work (see "3"), but wordpress just don't see it. What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

(the code from my php.ini is the following)

```
memory_limit = 256M

max_execution_time = 300;

max_input_vars = 1500;

suhosin_post_max_vars = 3000

suhosin_request_max_vars = 3000

suhosin_max_value_length = 1000000

upload_max_filesize = 30M
post_max_size = 10M
mysql.default_socket = "/kunden/tmp/mysql5.sock"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i can ask clarification using answer feature in here, but... @Marcel, it's not clear what "*wordpress just don't see it*" means a) Avada's Server Environment page shows a PHP Memory Limit or b) a lower Wordpress Memory limit?

I am guessing is b). In this case, have you edited wp-config.php and increased memory limit. e.g `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );`

Anyway, if your theme or plugins are consuming 256M memory and it is not a complex app or website, maybe you should considerate "leaner" themes and plugins and/or dedicated and managed Wordpress services like Dreampress by Dreamhost or WPEngine.